# Dynamic Routing Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement dynamic routing. I didn't know what I'm missing. Here I'm trying to render LunchContainer on the basic of groupId. Her I'm using react-router and react-router-dom.

Component Code

```
export class DashboardScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      ..........
              <Link className={classes.link} to={`/lunch/$groupId`>
                <Button className={classes.button}>
                  Lunch
                </Button>
              </Link>
           .......
    );
  }
}

const styles = theme => ({
  ......
});

export default withStyles(styles)(DashboardScreen);
```

I use App.js file for routing

```
import { LunchContainer } from "./components/dashboard/Lunch";

export class App extends Component {
           ....
          <Switch>
           ......
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/lunch/:grouId" component={LunchContainer} />
           .......
          </Switch>
         ....

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you use **`react-router-dom`** no need to use **`react-router`** separately, because **`react-router`** used as a core in **`react-router-dom`**

2) I want to change your render as below

```
render() {

  const { classes, match } = this.props;
  return (
    ..........
            <Link className={classes.link} to={`/lunch/${match.params.groupId}`>
              <Button className={classes.button}>
                Lunch
              </Button>
            </Link>
         .......
  );
}
```

3) I think this is your typo `<PrivateRoute exact path="/lunch/:grou`**`p`**`Id" component={LunchContainer} />`